# Como posso obter uma data 60 meses atrás?

Tags: sql-server

Eu quero pegar alguma data há 60 meses.

Estou em um projeto que mostra apenas os arquivos Enviados à 60 meses, mas são 60 meses e não 5 anos, talvez não faça alguma diferença.

Alguma idéia? Eu tentei usar datediff, mas não tenho sucesso. Eu quero fazer isso em SQL procedure

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()) - 5  AS VARCHAR)
```

Note que o "5" antes do varchar, refere-se ao 60 meses ou 5 anos, entretanto, ele quer 60 meses. Como eu poderia pegar esta data de 60 meses atrás.

Comment: Poste o código que você tentou com `datediff`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Na sua query, você deve usar [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS Hoje, DATEADD(M, -60, GETDATE()) AS [60MesesAtras]
```

Como você não forneceu mais detalhes em sua pergunta, isso é o máximo que posso te ajudar.

[**Exemplo no SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21440)

Comment: Obrigado gmsantos, eu não lembrava do dateadd... Que cara lerdo! Obrigado de verdade ;)